# WP_Query can't filter between two dates

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, custom-post-type, wordpress-rest-api

I am using WP Rest API as backend of a mobile app. The app is a simple todo list, where tasks have a `task_date`.

I came up with the following:

- `Task` is a custom post type
- `task_date` is a field created with ACF (date selector with `Ymd` format)

So, i am creating this endpoint

`GET /calendar - params { date_from, date_to}` (params are `Ymd` string dates).

which should return all tasks with `task_date` between `date_from` and `date_to`.

This is the code i've came up with:

```php
    public function get_task_calendar($req){

        $params = $req->get_params();


        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'task',
            'fields' => array("ID", "post_title"),
            'meta_query' => array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'task_date',
                    'compare' => '>=',
                    'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($params["date_from"])),
                    'type' => 'DATE'
                ),
                array(
                    'key' => 'task_date',
                    'compare' => '<=',
                    'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($params["date_to"])),
                    'type' => "DATE"
                )
            )
        );

        $query = new WP_Query($args);

        $results = $query->get_posts();

        return $results;


    }
```

I've seen other solutions where it is used a `BETWEEN` operator instead, but i had no success either. Unfortunately, ACF doesn't allow us to store this field as timestamp (which would be easier to compare), so i am casting it inside the query. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Can you try and leave out `'type' => 'DATE'`? https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments says, _“The ‘type’ DATE works with the ‘compare’ value BETWEEN only if the date is stored at the format YYYY-MM-DD”_ - I’m guessing that is probably the same for >=/<=. ACF stores the value as `YYYYMMDD` however, so if you do a mere string comparison here, I guess that should work.

Comment: Actually, ACF lets me choose how date is stored (different datestring formats), i chose `Ymd`. But i will try your suggestion to see if it works. Thanks.

Comment: No, not really - it lets you choose in what format you want it _shown_ in the edit view, and when you fetch the value to use in your templates - but the format it stores in the database is _always_ YYYYMMDD.

Comment: So, i don't need to cast the `task_date` field as date(), right? It is just a string comparison.

Comment: I can confirm that it worked comparing dates as string like you said. Thank you very much. Feel free to add it as an answer so i can check it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            array(
                'key' => 'task_date',
                'compare' => '>=',
                'value' => date("Ymd", strtotime($params["date_from"])),
                'type' => 'DATE'
            ),
```

Can you try and leave out `'type' => 'DATE'`?

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/classes/wp_meta_query/#accepted-arguments says,

> The `type` DATE works with the `compare` value `BETWEEN` only if the date is stored at the format `YYYY-MM-DD`.

I’m guessing that is probably the same for `>=`/`<=`.

ACF stores the value as `YYYYMMDD` however, so if you do a plain string comparison here, that should work.